# Angular 6 page not showing data from node backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I would like to display data returned from api in my front end using angular 6

here is what I have done : but data are not shoiwng up :

component.htm:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">Popular Movies</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let movie of movies; let i=index" class="col-md-2">
        <div *ngIf="i < 6">
        <img *ngIf="movie.poster_path" class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
        <h4>{{movie.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{movie.release_date}}</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-default" routerLink="/movie/{{movie.id}}">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.scss']
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
   movies: any;

 constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http, private location: Location, private moviesService: MoviesService) {
      this.movies = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.moviesService.getMovies(id)
      .then(movies => {
          console.log(movies);
          this.movies = this.movies;
        });
   });
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoviesService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/movies';


  constructor(private http: Http, private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }


  getMovies(id: string): Promise<any> {
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
                 .toPromise()
                 .then(this.handleData)
                 .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleData(res: any) {
       const body = res.json();
       console.log(body); // for development purposes only
       return body || {};
   }
 private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
     console.error('An error occurred', error); // for development purposes only
     return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
 }
}
```

when i run my app there is no data displayed which are returned from api , when i check rensponse in web browser there is data returned without error,

why data are not showing up in my app? any suggestion what I might b edoing wrong? thanks

Comment: you didnt see any data print by console.log()?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the handleData method of your service.

You declare the variable `body` as a constant, meaning that its value is immutable.  Therefore, your attempts to set its value to res.json() are ignored.

Instead, change this to:

`let body = res.json();` and you should be all set.

**EDIT:**

Also note that that `res.json()` is unecessary; the call to json() is applied automatically. You don't need to do this in Angular 6.  And use the HttpClient service, not Http.

Comment: oky can you please show me how that handle should look after removing res.json ,?

Comment: MoviesComponent.html:19 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you got a `movies` is undefined error in your development tools when you hit F12.

The reason is because your template loaded first before the `movies` data have its value from the server *(async call on promise)* then the template is trying look for the `movies` variable in `*ngFor="let movie of movies; let i=index"` and 
 angular caught the error which is undefined.

To avoid this do not show the template while data is not yet available. You can use `*ngIf="movies"` or much better use the combination of `ng-template`, `ng-container` and `ngTemplateOutlet` to display loading indicator.

```
<div *ngIf="movies" class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let movie of movies; let i=index" class="col-md-2">
        <div *ngIf="i < 6">
        <img *ngIf="movie.poster_path" class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
        <h4>{{movie.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{movie.release_date}}</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-default" routerLink="/movie/{{movie.id}}">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I usual do is using `ng-template`, `ng-container` and `*ngTemplateOutlet`:

```
<div class="panel-body">

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="movies ? content : loading"></ng-container>

<ng-template #content>
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let movie of movies; let i=index" class="col-md-2">
        <div *ngIf="i < 6">
        <img *ngIf="movie.poster_path" class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
        <h4>{{movie.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{movie.release_date}}</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-default" routerLink="/movie/{{movie.id}}">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loading>
   <div>loading data...</div>
</ng-template>

</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Found the culprit.

You have an assignment mistake on `ngOnInit()`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.moviesService.getMovies(id)
      .then(movies => {
          console.log(movies);
          // Instead of this.movies = this.movies; use:
          this.movies = movies;
        });
   });
  }
```

Comment: no error in console web browser i get this : Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
movies.component.ts:24 undefined

Comment: @HotZellah i updated my answer, just found what causing this